# Parse not deleting local PIN

Tags: android, parse-platform

In my Android application `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);`  i then use

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(PARSE_TABLE_NAME);
        final ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        query.whereEqualTo("User", currentUser);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(final List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (final ParseObject userState : scoreList) {
                        final String LESSON_TAG = userState.getString("lessonTag");
                        userState.unpinInBackground(PARSE_TABLE_NAME_PIN + LESSON_TAG, new DeleteCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                try {
                                    userState.pin(PARSE_TABLE_NAME_PIN + LESSON_TAG);
                                } catch (ParseException f) {
                                    f.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    callback.onDownloadSuccess();
                } else {
                    callback.onError();
                }
            }
        });
```

Now if ever i have pinned any object for Table the above query always returns from a local PIN. This is NOT fetching data from the server. How can i force the above to fetch from the server and NOT the pin ?

Comment: Is it real code? Pinned ojbects will return only with  `query.fromLocalDatastore()`

Comment: Yes this is real code ?

Comment: then according code query would return rows from table not from local database, because you don't refer to it. Your query returns all rows where `User` equals current user.